# mkmap zoom on user location - Xcode

Tags: xcode, dictionary, location, zooming

i have this code..

```
-(IBAction)getlocation {
mapview.showsUserLocation = YES;
[mapview setCenterCoordinate:mapview.userLocation.coordinate animated:YES];
```

and also i have a pin with fixed coordinates.. what i want is when the button for userlocation is pressed, i want the view to zoom out from the pin and then travel and zoom back in to the user location. my current code just travels to the current location. how do i do that zoom-out from pin, then travel, and finally zoom-in? thank you in advance..

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
[_mapView setCenterCoordinate:pinCoordinate zoomLevel:minZoomValue animated:YES];
```

(should zoom the map out from the pin)

then call:

```
mapview.showsUserLocation = YES;
[mapview setCenterCoordinate:mapview.userLocation.coordinate animated:YES];
```

to zoom the map to the user's coordinate. (Optionally you can set the desired zoom level as shown above)

Comment: Did you replace "pinCoordinate" with the coordinate of the pin you are zooming out from?